# Ubuntu 18.04 on Asus TP200SA: black logon screen

Tags: asus, 18.04

I managed to install Ubuntu 18.04 onto Asus TP200SA primary (microSD) drive. The problem: after I log on, graphics/sound work as expected, the highest resolution is possible.

However, after startup, the login screen is black. If I press "Enter", enter password and press "Enter" again, screen turns on and normal logon is taking place.

At logon screen, I cannot use switching screens (Ctrl-Alt-F2 etc), and can't choose login options (since I see nothing).

Using "nomodeset" helps (display is turned on), but after logon notebook switches to 800x600, which is too inferior to use for real.

Is it possible to turn on display when logon screen is shown? I tried closing/opening the lid, display momentarily flickers on, but switches off almost immediately.

Answer (score 1):

When I rotate the laptop, the screen shows up. Then I click the top right menu and lock the screen from rotating.